# NPM: revert installed packages

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm working in a Node.js application with **npm** and **git**. When I add new npm packages I use `npm <package> --save` and it is saved on '*package.json*' file.

The thing is that when I use `git reset --hard`, the '*package.json*' file is reverted, but the packages are still installed.

The question is: how can I uninstall automatically npm packages that I have installed before the `git reset --hard`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After reverting, you can try npm prune  option. This will unbuild all the packages not there in package.json

```
npm prune
```